# Retrieve the column names from an empty MySQL query result

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to retrieve the column names of a query that returns no data?

I'm using (somewhat) complicated queries such as:

```
SELECT 
    i.*,
    ic1.permalink as category_permalink, 
    ic1.title as category_title,
    ic1.sid as category_sid,
    ic2.permalink as hook_category_permalink,
    ic2.title as hook_category_title,
    ic2.sid as hook_category_sid
FROM item i
    LEFT JOIN item_to_item_category itic ON i.sid = itic.item_sid
    LEFT JOIN item_category ic1 ON ic1.sid = itic.item_category_sid
    LEFT JOIN item_category ic2 ON ic1.hook = ic2.sid
WHERE i.uid = ''
LIMIT 0,1
```

The result of this query would be empty because of `WHERE i.uid = ""`. Is there a way how to find the column names when there's no result?

Please note that I'm aware of solutions using `DESCRIBE` and `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='person';` but I need a more flexible solution that will fit these multicolumn queries.

Please also note that I am still using the original PHP MySQL extention (so no MySQLi, and no PDO).

Anyone?

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to accomplish, but could you edit your question to include some context?  Why do you need to know the column titles for a query that returns no data?

Comment: At the very least, state which DB extension you're using.

Comment: The reason why I need to do this is rather a long story. It's for a backoffice I've created. The DB extention is just the traditional PHP  MySQL extention. It's time for an upgrade, so it seems.

Comment: Please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PDO, try [`PDOStatement->getColumnMeta()`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.getColumnMeta). For mysqli, there's [`mysqli_result->fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.fetch_fields), [`mysqli_result->fetch_field()`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.fetch_field) and [`mysqli_result->fetch_field_direct()`](http://php.net/mysqli_result.fetch_field_direct). For mysql, replace it with PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's high time to upgrade to MySQLi!

Comment: @maartenmachiels: PDO has a nicer interface. See the answers to [Getting the syntax of prepared statements right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9425405/) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling the query from PHP. You can call [mysqli_fetch_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) even with an emtpy query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple class based on *mysqli*. This method will work on empty tables as well. Of course, add your own error checking as needed.

Success will return a numerically indexed array of column names from $table.
Failure or non-string input will return **FALSE**.

```
class mysqlz extends mysqli {

    function fetch_table_columns($table) {
        if(!is_string($table)) {
            return false;
        } elseif($obj = $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table)) {
                while($fields = $obj->fetch_object()) {
                    $columns[] = $fields->Field;
                }
                return $columns;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

To use, first instantiate your database as usual:
`$mysql = new mysqlz($host, $user, $pass, $database);`

Then, call the method to retrieve the column names:
`$columns = $mysql->fetch_table_columns("table_name_here");`

Depending on your table, the resulting array should **var_dump()** similar to this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "id" [1]=> string(10) "first_name" [2]=> string(9) "last_name" }
```

If method returns false (var_dump returns `bool(false)`) you can check the current error with `$mysqlz->error`. For more information on error checking, take a look at the PHP mysqli manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

Answer (score 0):

For AdoDB you can use:

```
$db->Execute("SELECT .......");  
$colInfo = $res->FieldTypesArray();
```

The output is similar to method `MetaColumns($table)`, but you can use it on every result set not only for tables (including joins).
It works for empty results or empty tables too.

Thanks to [outis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90527/outis),
I found this function after searching "fetch_field()" in adoDBs mysql-driver :D