# Insert a longtext for forum in DB error with: " & '

Tags: php, sql

i'm actually creating a forum from scratch. To insert in my DB the message i use this:

```
'INSERT INTO forum_sujets VALUES("", "'.$steamprofile['personaname'].'",  "'.$steamprofile['steamid'].'", "'.$_POST['titre'].'", "'.$_POST['message'].'", "'.$date.'", "'.$date.'", "'.$_GET['id'].'", "0" , "0", "0")';
```

But if I insert a text with a " or a ' it create error. How can i fix this ?

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with inputs!

Comment: Are you using PDO?

Comment: no i don't use pdo

Comment: Nowadays, to avoid sql injection, use PDO or MySQLi. Use Prepared Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should absolutely avoid directly using raw input in SQL statements as that's a critical security risk for your application. Use prepared statements instead. See [How to change from mysql to pdo using prepared statements in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211919/how-to-change-from-mysql-to-pdo-using-prepared-statements-in-php) but you can also google, there are many examples online.

As a bonus, this should address any issues you have with spaces and special characters.

I know it may seem like an annoyance but this is a classic and very real security risk, please move to prepared statements.